# How to reset preview after setting aspect ratio on Cropper by fengyuanchen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm one tiny detail away from getting the awesome cropper (fengyuanchen - GitHub) working how I need it. I'm able to programmatically set the aspect ratio when my form loads, but this breaks the preview window. I've checked out the documentation where I can but sadly I'm not versed in JQuery enough to be able to make sense of it. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="img-container">
    <img id="image" src="test.jpg" alt="Picture" runat="server" /><!-- ############# IMAGE ###########-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="docs-preview clearfix">
    <div class="img-preview preview-lg"></div><!-- preview image-->
    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript/jquery which runs after the page has loaded:

```
function aspect() {
    var $image = $('#image');
    var $preview = $('img-preview');
    var asp = document.getElementById('hidAspectRatio').value;
    $image.cropper('setAspectRatio', asp);
    //$preview('resetPreview');
    return false;
}
```

the commented out line is where I think I need to call something which resets the preview div, but I can't figure out what I should call. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I realise I need a (#) hash sign in front of the line var $preview = $('#img-preview'); - just missed that off by error - that line actually isn't doing anything yet

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question completely, but you can programmatically set the aspect ratio within the js like so:

```
var options = {
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9, //can also use other values like 4/3, 1, 2/3
    preview: '.img-preview',
    crop: function (e) {
      $dataX.val(Math.round(e.x));
      $dataY.val(Math.round(e.y));
      $dataHeight.val(Math.round(e.height));
      $dataWidth.val(Math.round(e.width));
      $dataRotate.val(e.rotate);
      $dataScaleX.val(e.scaleX);
      $dataScaleY.val(e.scaleY);
    }
  };
```

This code sample comes from the main.js within the [Cropper Demo Page](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/).